# How to pull out a substring out of the url?

Tags: regex

I need to pull out C5044SGXAU out of the following url:

```
    <div class="zg_itemImageImmersion"><a href="http://www.website.com/Doggy-PIC-14-Pitbull-Induction-1500-Matt/dp/C5044SGXAU/ref=zg_bs_3741261_1"><img src="http://dog.images-website.com/images/I/41dXgzYztML._SL160_SL150_.jpg" alt="Doggy PIC-14 Pitbull Induction Cookt..." title="Doggy PIC-14 Pitbull Induction Cookt..." onload="if (typeof uet == 'function') { uet('af'); }"></a></div>
```

I'm trying to get this as a result:

```
C5044SGXAU
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex

`http:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fY0cX0/1)

Comment: Hey Venky, it doesn't seem to work when in my program. It displays the following...

http://www.website.com/Doggy-PIC-14-Pitbull-Induction-1500-Matt/dp/C5044SGXAU/ref=zg_bs_3741261_1
"><img src="http:

Comment: Can you post the part of your program where you are using this regex?

Comment: Not sure if this would help but here it is...

    set(#dddf, $find regular expression(#ddd, "http:\\/\\/[^\\/]+\\/[^\\/]+\\/[^\\/]+\\/([^\\/]+)\\/[^\\/]+"), "Global")

Comment: variable #ddd holds the original string above.

Comment: Can You try the following 

(http:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/)[^\/]+(\/[^\/]+)

Comment: Hey Venky it's putting out the following:

http:// website.com/Doggy-PIC-14-Pitbull-Induction-1500-Matt/dp/5ddB64O0S/ref=zg_bs_3741261_1
"><img src="http:

Comment: Can you get me the code out of this?

http:// website.com/Doggy-PIC-14-Pitbull-Induction-1500-Matt/dp/5ddB64O0S/ref=zg_bs_3741‌​261_1
"><img src="http: